How to handle colliders when using animations Unity3D?
With my character controller I was only using the default collider that comes with the default controller component. Now that I have added animations for 10 or so different movements, the player hit box becomes extremely inconsistent since most of these animations move the player around in different positions/scales/rotations.
I added colliders into my 3D rigged character model that I made and placed them in the head, arms, upper back, lower back, legs, etc. But that’s as far as I’ve gotten so far.
Is a standard approach to somehow “ignore” the main character controller collider and instead use all those small colliders that I’ve attached across the rigged character model for collision checks? So basically the character controller would handle movement, but not collisions (if that’s possible or advised).
So then when my player crouches and the crouch animation plays, all those small colliders will provide accurate hitboxes since they’re moving in sync with the scale, rotation and position of the player whilst an animation is playing. I hope I’m on the right track here.

I think it depends on the "scale" of your visuals. If "limbs" etc. play an important part, then colliders on those parts make sense. With smaller characters and other objects, you have to look closely to see if they're actually contacting; and not just "passing through and over" (which is actually the case); so, "one collider" may be enough with small characters; since the "movement area" is quite small in this case (relative to everything else).
